# Batch/cmd reader for vision impared

Tags: batch-file, cmd, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, vision

One of my friends is blind and relies on sound to control his computer. His screen reader doesnt read cmd so i was wondering if there is a way to somehow use VB and batch to create an accessible batch game without adding in a lot of programming.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting: all (decent) screen readers read Cmd nowadays. There are problems with Cygwin, for example, but Cmd and Windows PowerShell are read quite well.
Well, let's suppose he does have something that doesn't read Cmd. That would dramatically increase the difficulty level of debugging his batch files since he won't be able to do `echo something` or similar things.
but as for writing itself, he should go for a text editor (I suggest AkelPad, but it's up to him what to choose).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, he is using Jaws Screen Reader which is a good screen reader.

Comment: If he uses JAWS (which I do, btw), then he should have no problems reading neither Cmd nor PowerShell :). If he does have any difficulties, please elaborate in the comments, I'll help with pleasure.